# ubuntu 12.04 slows down while installing updates or using software center

Tags: updates, download-speed

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 inside windows 7, and love to try it,but I don't know why it slows down and windows become grey while installing updates or using software center and that causes "un disfonctionnement total" of all system can I find how to ride over this?

Comment: What are the specs of your pc?!

Answer (score 1):

If a window becomes gray, it means that it is busy.

You have some options to "fix" this:

1. You can try to play around with `nice` levels: `sudo snice 19 software-center` while starting the update.
2. Add more RAM to your system.
3. Migrate to SSD.

Answer (score 1):

The software center and update manager both are pretty ressource-heavy applications. Depending on your system you might want to consider using command-line tools as a replacement.

To install software:

```
sudo apt-get install packagename
```

To update your system (in this order):

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

For `.deb` files you can use gdebi as an alternative to the Ubuntu Software Center:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```